# Visual Studio for Mac: Hide DLL loads from Application Output

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

Is it possible to stop Visual Studio for Mac from filling the Application Output window with all the DLLs it has loaded?

On Windows I can right click in the window and uncheck 'Module Load Messages'.

How can I do the same on Mac?

[image]

Comment: There is no feature by feature mapping, but you can suggest https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html

Comment: 9 months after, and this came up in my first google search on how to remove all that noise. I find it baffling that considering I have "logging -> moduleLoad = false" in my launch.json, VS4Mac doesn't honor it. This kind of stuff is basic, I find it ridiculous that we need to suggest something that's so basic in everyday development.